# How can I test HTTPS configuration in a LAN?

Tags: ssl, testing, web-server

I'm developing a website that should be used with HTTPS. I am developing the site on my Windows machine and I have a Linux machine on the same LAN where I test my websites. I don't have a DNS-server on the LAN so I use IP-addresses to access the website.

On the server I use Ubuntu Server and Nginx web server. Is there any easy way I can test the HTTPS configuration in my LAN? E.g if I generate a SSL-certificate myself, but I don't have a domain name to set up it with. Any recommendations for testing? Or should I use a subdomain `test.example.com` and put an A record to my local IP-adress to the test server E.g. `192.168.1.10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generate a self-signed certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)* for Nginx. [Configure Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule) to use it.

Edit the `hosts` file on your computer, add the domain your testing. 
On *nix, it's `/etc/hosts` in Windows it's `%systemroot%\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts`. 
Add a line similar to `www.example.com 192.0.2.5` (substitute the domain and your server's IP).

You should now be able to browse out to `www.example.com` and see the test page on your server.

<sub>*Ignore the part at the end of these directions, it's for Apache only.</sub>